# Proof that $\forall r \in \Bbb Q$, if $3r-\frac12s\in\Bbb{\bar Q}$ then $s\in\Bbb{\bar Q}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Proof that $\forall r \in \Bbb Q$, if $3r-\frac12s\in\Bbb{\bar Q}$ then $s\in\Bbb{\bar Q}$

I'm unsure about the notation in this proof (specifically what $\Bbb{\bar Q}$ means) and how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could mean algebraic (or topological) closure of $\mathbb Q$

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ can mean the complement of the set $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e. the irrationals.

You can prove the statement by contrapositive by proving $s\in\mathbb{Q}\implies 3r-\frac{1}{2}s\in\mathbb{Q},\forall r\in\mathbb{Q}$.

We assume $s=\frac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $r=\frac{p_2}{q_2}$ for some $p_1,p_2,q_1,q_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ since $s,r\in\mathbb{Q}$. It is then straightforward to prove that $3r-\frac{1}{2}s$ can be simplified into a form which has integer numerator and denominator, thus being rational. I'll leave the last step to you. Hope this helps!